# How can I replace next frames using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a folder named `frames` with images, named `frame0001.png`, `frame0002.png`, `frame0003.png`, etc, all the way to `frame0061.png` (or `frames/frame%04d.png` using FFmpeg).

I have an input video file simply named `video.mp4`.

Starting at `00:00:03` (3rd second), I want next frames to be **replaced** with all frames from under `frames` folder, and then save the output video as `output.mp4` using ffmpeg.exe.

For example, starting at 3 seconds, next 61 frames (because there are 61 frame files under the `frames` folder) in `video.mp4` will be overwritten with the frames under `frames` folder.

Which command-line options should I pass to FFmpeg to apply this task?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -itsoffset 3 -i frame%04d.png -lavfi "overlay=eof_action=pass" out.mp4`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов Thank you, the command you provided works. Can you post an answer instead of a comment so I mark it as accepted?